# Python: Convert columns into date format and extract order

Tags: python, date, datetime, converters

I am asking for help in transforming values into date format.

I have following data structure:

```
ID  ACT1        ACT2        ACT3        ACT4
1   154438.0    154104.0    155321.0    155321.0
2   154042.0    154073.0    154104.0    154104.0
...
```

The number in columns ACT1-4 need to be converted. Some rows contain NaN values.

I found that following function helps me to get a Gregorian date:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
gregorian = datetime.strptime('1582/10/15', "%Y/%m/%d")
modified_date = gregorian + timedelta(days=154438)
datetime.strftime(modified_date, "%Y/%m/%d")
```

It would be great to know how I can apply this transformation to all columns except for "ID" and whether the approach is correct (or could be improved).

After the transformation is applied, I need to extract the order of column items, sorted by date in ascending order. For instance

```
ID ORDER
1  ACT1, ACT3, ACT4, ACT2
2  ACT2, ACT1, ACT3, ACT4
```

Thank you!

Comment: why apply date function at all when the columns are already numerical?

Comment: I need to see the actual dates.

Comment: Your order for the second column is wrong I think.  Also for the first column

Comment: @Christopher you state that you want columns that contain the ACTs ordered correctly but this isn't calculating the dates. Are you wanting the dates to be returned to another file in the right order?

Comment: @user3483203 order of both rows is correct but these second contains ACT3 and ACT4 with equal order.

Comment: @EamonnKenny the second row says it is sorted as `ACT2, ACT1`, but `154042` is less than `154073`

Comment: @user3483203 absolutely, sorry. I looked at this and thought the same thing and then said "no that's not right, but you are right".

Comment: I agree. As I did not have the actual dates yet, the order was only exemplary, excuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two questions here.

1) To change to datetime:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'ID']
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].applymap(lambda x: datetime.strptime('1582/10/15', "%Y/%m/%d") + timedelta(days=x) if np.isfinite(x) else x)
```

2) To get the sorted column names:

```
df['ORDER'] = df.loc[:, cols].apply(lambda dr: ','.join(df.loc[:, cols].columns[dr.dropna().argsort()]), axis=1)
```

Note: the dropna above will omit columns with NaT values from the order string.

Comment: What if I have NaN values? "('cannot convert float NaN to integer', 'occurred at index ACT1')"

Comment: In order to select every except for the first column,I did `df.loc[:, df.columns != 'ID'].applymap(lambda x: datetime.strptime('1582/10/15', "%Y/%m/%d") + timedelta(days=x))`

Comment: Re: the NaN values, is that happening where we are converting to datetime (first line)? I thought your 'ID' was an index which is why I did not filter for a subset of columns.

Comment: No, ID is a column indeed. And the NaN values are in each of the columns. Some have more, some less.

Comment: I tried: `df.loc[:, df.columns != 'ID'].applymap(lambda x: datetime.strptime('1582/10/15', "%Y/%m/%d") + timedelta(days=x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)`and it seems to work. However, it won't show the ID.

Comment: Ok, please change your question to include the NaN condition along with logic of how sorts should take place given a NaN. Should rows with NaNs be dropped? Should NaNs default to 1582/10/15?

Comment: Just did. I think yes, when merging the order, the NaN should be dropped.

Comment: Edited answer to reassign values to your df which will preserve your ID column. If you don't want to reassign you can always make a `.copy()` of your df.

Comment: "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional". The script seems to work, only the assignment of `df.loc[:, cols] = ` seems to be an issue. Part 2) seems to work perfectly. Thanks already, I'll mark as solved, though the error puzzles me.

Answer (score 1):

First I would make the input column comma separated so that its much easier to handle of the form:

```
ID,ACT1,ACT2,ACT3,ACT4
1,154438.0,154104.0,155321.0,155321.0
2,154042.0,154073.0,154104.0,154104.0
```

Then you can read each line using a CSV reader, extracting key,value pairs that have your column names as keys. Then you pop the ID off that dictionary to get its value ie, 1,2,etc. And you can then reorder according to the value which is the date. The code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
from operator import itemgetter

idAndTuple = {}
with open('time.txt') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    myID = row.pop('ID',None)
    reorderedList = sorted(row.items(), key = itemgetter(1))
    idAndTuple[myID] = reorderedList
    print( myID, reorderedList )
```

The result when you run this is:

```
1 [('ACT2', '154104.0'), ('ACT1', '154438.0'), ('ACT3', '155321.0'), ('ACT4', '155321.0')]
2 [('ACT1', '154042.0'), ('ACT2', '154073.0'), ('ACT3', '154104.0'), ('ACT4', '154104.0')]
```

which I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: you just iterate over each reorderedList then to obtain the [0] part for column name and [1] part for value and use your georgian calendar converter to perform the conversion.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer! Yet, above script worked bit better for my case.